# Missing comma before start of a new alter operation. (near "CHARACTER SET")

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

## Mysql - phpmyadmin

What's wrong with this query?

```
ALTER TABLE `invoices` 
CHANGE `status` `status` ENUM('paid','due','canceled','partial','cheque') 
CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_general_ci` NOT NULL DEFAULT `due`;
```

I am getting this error:

**Missing comma before start of a new alter operation. (near "CHARACTER SET")** and not able to run this query on live server. Query was generated when I changed the table structure on my localhost during development.

I also tried below query mentioned in many threads but it also give same above error:

`` ALTER TABLE `invoices` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; ``

Comment: Try `DEFAULT 'String'`

Comment: Can you write the full query please @PM77-1

Comment: This is not a mysql error message. Maybe run your query directly in the mysql client. Also, what PM meant: you are using the wrong quotes, ` ` instead of `''` ìn ```DEFAULT `due` ``` (it's unrelated to this problem, but will get you once you get around it).

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why. I also faced the **same** issue.

Though it appears like:

> When removed both CHARACTER and COLLATE part from SQL, parser works fine.

**i.e**

#### Before

```sql
ALTER TABLE `place` CHANGE COLUMN `plc_location_type` `gplc_location_type` ENUM('LOCATION') CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL;
```

#### After

```sql
ALTER TABLE `place` CHANGE COLUMN `plc_location_type` `gplc_location_type` ENUM('LOCATION') NOT NULL;
```

***REFERENCE:***
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/229

*Good luck!*

Answer (score 0):

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name 
CHANGE old_column_name1 new_col_name1 Data Type,
CHANGE old_column_name2 new_col_name2 Data Type,
CHANGE old_column_name3 new_col_name3 Data Type;
```

Comment: You need to add some explanation to your answer